# add javascript code and html to php echo

Tags: php

hello please help me add this java script to echo ;  and replace  xxxxx with $url

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/kt_player/kt_player.js"></script>
<div id="kt_player" style="visibility: hidden">
    <a href="http://adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">This page requires Adobe Flash Player</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {
        hide_controlbar: '1',
        hide_style: 'fade',
        preview_url: 'http://www.kernel-video-sharing.com/kt_player/poster.jpg',
        bt: '5',
        video_url: 'xxxxx',
        video_url_text: '720p'
    };

    var params = {allowfullscreen: 'true', allowscriptaccess: 'always'};
    kt_player('kt_player', '/kt_player/kt_player.swf', '854', '480', flashvars, params);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to `echo` the variable, like this:

```
// your code

video_url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',

// your code
```